# Explain Bash Script

Tags: bash, azure, azure-aks

Can someone please help me to understand this bash script? I am really struggling with first block and last block specifically if and then blocks of the code.

```
if [[ $# -ne 2 ]] ; then
    echo 'Cluster name, Azure Subscription ID required as input arguments.'
    echo 'Example usage: ./create_blob_container.sh <CLUSTER_NAME> <ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID>'
    exit 1
fi

MAX_CHAR_CLUSTER_NAME=8

CLUSTER_NAME=${1}
ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=${2}
ARM_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_TFSTATE_NAME=${CLUSTER_NAME}tfstate$(echo ${ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID}|cut -c1- 
8)

RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME=stack-tfstate-rg
CONTAINER_NAME=tfstate

LOCATION=westeurope
SKU=Standard_LRS
ENCRYPTION_SERVICES=blob

if [ ${#CLUSTER_NAME} -gt ${MAX_CHAR_CLUSTER_NAME} ]; then
    echo "ERROR: Project name is too long (${#CLUSTER_NAME} chars). Maximal number of allowed 
chars is ${MAX_CHAR_CLUSTER_NAME}. Exiting..."
    exit 1`enter code here`
fi
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you mark it as solved ?

Answer (score 1):

The first block  means if the number of the positional parametre passed to the script is not equals to 2 then the script will execute 2 echo and exit.

```bash
if [[ $# -ne 2 ]]
```

Here a [link](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/How_to_use_positional_parameters) that might help you.

The last block means if the length of the string  stored in the  variable CLUSTER_NAME which is the first position parametre is greather than  MAX_CHAR_CLUSTER_NAME which is 8

```bash
if [ ${#CLUSTER_NAME} -gt ${MAX_CHAR_CLUSTER_NAME} ]; then
```

Another [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-find-length-of-string-in-bash-script/)